# jQuery.ParseJson didn't return a value from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a  div that will store a value from DB that parse from JSON

```
<div id='nsnt' class="huge">  </div>
```

I have a getdata.php to getdata from mysqldb

getdata.php

```
<?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("musicstore");
    $strSQL = "SELECT count(song_id) as cnt FROM song ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);

    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);

?>
```

I use var_dump on $resultArray it's return a data perfectly

On my index.php I have a jQuery function to return data from getdata.php and display on `<div id='nsnt' class="huge">  </div>` like this

```
<script>

function getDataFromDb()
{
    $.ajax({ 
                url: "~/getdata.php" ,
                type: "POST",
                data: ''

            })
            .success(function(result) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    if(obj != '')
                    {
                          //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                          $("#nsnt").empty();
                          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                              var m = val["cnt"];
                              $('#nsnt').append( m );
                          });
                    }
}

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 1000);   // 1000 = 1 second
</script>
```

It's doesn't return anything

Comment: where should I put it on ?

Comment: check your browser console for errors...should be several that need fixing

Comment: oh I found `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions . use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Success should be one of ajax properties, otherwise use `.done()`, try this :

```
$.ajax({ 
            url: "~/getdata.php" ,
            type: "POST",
            data: '',
            success : function(result) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                if(obj != '')
                {
                      //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                      $("#nsnt").empty();
                      $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                          var m = val["cnt"];
                          $('#nsnt').append( m );

                      });
                }
            }
        });
```

or

```
 $.ajax({ 
            url: "~/getdata.php" ,
            type: "POST",
            data: '' 
        }).done(function(result) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                if(obj != '')
                {
                      //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                      $("#nsnt").empty();
                      $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                          var m = val["cnt"];
                          $('#nsnt').append( m );

                      });
                };
       });
```